# PHPExcel not writing file correctly

Tags: php, phpexcel, forms

My website allows users to upload `.xls`, `.xlsx`, and `.csv` files. If the file is not `.csv`, it is converted over to one and saves to the server. The problem is that the code I have isn't saving the file. Instead, it is only saving one cell that is blank. What is wrong with my code, and how can I edit it to have it accomplish the task I seek?

```
require_once('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'); 
require_once("mcl_Oci.php");
$filename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ($_FILES['uploaded']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        die("Upload failed with error code #" . $_FILES['uploaded']['error']);
    }

    if($ext == 'xls') {

        $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
        $inputFileName = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

            $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
            $objWriter->save('abc.csv'); //THIS IS WHERE IT ERRORS//


        $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r'); 

            while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
        }       
        echo 'Your .xls file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';


    } elseif($ext == 'csv'){
        $inputFileType = 'CSV';
        $inputFileName = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

            $objWriter->save('abc.csv');

        $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r');
        while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
        }   
        echo 'Your .csv file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';

    } elseif($ext == 'xlsx') {
        $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';

        $inputFileName = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

        $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

        $objWriter->save(str_replace('.xlsx', '.csv', $inputFileName));

            $objWriter->save('abc.csv');

        $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r');

        while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
        }   
        echo 'Your .xlsx file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';     
    }

    else {
        echo "This is not an accepted file type. Please save as either '*.csv' or '*.xls' and re-upload.";
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I have my code working completely for `.csv` files. However, it does not work for `.xls` or `.xlsx`.

Comment: DON'T assume that a file with an `.xls` is an Excel file, it's as likely to be a csv or an html file that's simply been given an extension of .xls.... use the `PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify()` to find out what the filetype really is and create the reader based on that rather than assuming the uploader has "got it right"

Comment: Okay, I'll definitely update based on that info before final release of this portion of my website. However, seeing as I am creating the `.xls` from Microsoft Excel, wouldn't that mean the file is going to be correct no matter what? Thus, it shouldn't be error'ing the way it is.

Comment: Your loop through the $loadedSheetNames is saving to the same csv file for every worksheet (even if the last worksheet in the set is empty)

Comment: ^^When I removed the $loadedSheetNames section, it works the way it is intended! Thank you very much, @MarkBaker. It now only errors `Fatal error: Call to a member function getHighestDataColumn() on a non-object in <directory> on line 128` for `.xls` files

Comment: Check that you're actually executing `getHighestDataColumn()` against a worksheet object, and not against a null or false

Comment: I am not executing that function at all. I believe it may be in a class file. Is there any way to have the program run without running that function?

Comment: It's kind of difficult to simply say "stop running something essential that you need to work" and expect things to work correctly: a bit like taking engine out of your car because it makes a noise, yet still expecting the car to drive.... I can't solve that problem without a lot more detail, perhaps a stack dump or similar might help.... at the very least, I need to know what your code is doing at the point where that error occurs

Comment: @MarkBaker I have figured it out, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if($ext='xls') {
```

is doing an assigment, making **ALL** files be `xls`. It should be

```
if($ext == 'xls') {
        ^^---note the doubled "=" signs.
```

You have this exact same error in all of your `if()` tests.

As well, you don't seem to ever bother checking if the file uploads were successful, which is a very bad thing to do. Never assume success. Always assume failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise:

```
if ($_FILES['uploaded']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code #" . $_FILES['uploaded']['error']);
}
```

Comment: Up for catching the dumb mistake, however the problem still persists. Thanks though! Do you see any other problems?

Comment: Hard to tell. You seem to practice the "random indentation" school of code formatting, so your code is very hard to follow.

Comment: lol, no the FTP I am using doesn't make copying/pasting code easy xD. I'll use jsfiddle to clean it up and reupdate the code haha! Sorry

Comment: Updated, and I also added the error message - which does not appear to do anything.

Comment: you have your csv `fopen()` inside the xls section, so if you'r eprocessing csvs, `$files` never gets set, and your fgetcsv will fail and return boolean false.

Comment: ^This fixed the problem when uploading .csv files. The other two still act similarly. Thanks very much for helping the noob lol!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that finally allowed me to upload single-sheet `.xlsx`, `.xls`, and `.csv` files. After uploading, as stated in OP, I convert any `.xlsx` or `.xls` into `.csv` and save it into the directory.

```
    require_once('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'); 
    require_once("mcl_Oci.php");
    $filename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ($_FILES['uploaded']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        die("Upload failed with error code #" . $_FILES['uploaded']['error']);
    }

    if($ext == 'xls') {

        $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
        $inputFileName = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');



        $objWriter->save(str_replace('.xls', '.csv', $inputFileName));

            $objWriter->save('abc.csv');


        $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r'); 

            while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
        }       
        echo 'Your .xls file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';


    } elseif($ext == 'csv'){
        $inputFileType = 'CSV';
        $inputFileName = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

            $objWriter->save('abc.csv');

        $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r');
        while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
        }   
        echo 'Your .csv file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';

    } elseif($ext == 'xlsx') {
        $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';

        $inputFileName = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

        $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

        $objWriter->save(str_replace('.xlsx', '.csv', $inputFileName));

            $objWriter->save('abc.csv');

        $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r');

        while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
        }   
        echo 'Your .xlsx file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';     
    }

    else {
        echo "This is not an accepted file type. Please save as either '*.csv' or '*.xls' and re-upload.";
    }
```